# drainQueueLocked: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned

Tags: android, database

> drainQueueLocked: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned

I got this error when clicking on search button on main activity and entering details

> (itemdetails.java activity)

of item that is retrieved from database.
Sometimes i don't get this error at all.
 I am also getting security errors sometimes, but that's for another question i suppose.

Comment: I dont think you should be worried about random logs, unless you have problem in app

Comment: so i should ignore these errors, thanks.